# WebFlux RouterFunction and Handler returning Flux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

Are there any examples for Handler method and RouterFunction returning a Flux? Configuring the following handler on a RouterFunction

```
class MyHandler {
    public Flux<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        return Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed())
                .flatMap(i -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON).bodyValue(i));

    }
}
```

gives error

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert reactor.core.publisher.Flux<org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse> to reactor.core.publisher.Mono<org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse>
```

as the handler function always returns a Mono

`Mono<T> handle(ServerRequest request);`

In my case I'm looking at sending flux as response instead of collecting them into a Mono.

Comment: The `ServerResponse` can contain a `Flux`, you don't need to collect them into a `Mono`. So baiscally you need to reverse what you are doing. Something like `Mono.just(ServerResponse.ok().body(Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed(), Integer.class));` The return type is thus always `Mono<ServerResponse` as there will always be 1 response which can contain 0 or more results.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, your suggestion again forces me to wrap all results in a single response, if I'm sending a list of tickets I want to be able to emit each ticket as it's computed from a long running background job as a response  instead of wrapping all of them in a mono and giving a single response.

Comment: Again it is a single response which can contain a flux. There is always just 1 answer. You don't need to wrap them in a mono, the body of the `ServerResponse` is a `Flux`. The flux you create in your long running process. You could even make this en Server Sent Event Emitter or whatever you like it to be.

Comment: @M.Deinum Got you, I'll try this. Thanks! just to be sure, in this way I open a http response which keeps emitting values from Flux over http/2 on Netty? am I right?

Comment: Yes. See my answer (which contains an error, let me fix that).

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading/understanding the `Mono<ServerResponse>`. There is always just 1 `ServerResponse`, you can send only 1 response to the client. The same as with regular Servlet API you can only have 1 `HttpServletResponse` so 1 answer. The answer howerver can contain a flux.

```java
class MyHandler {
  public Mono<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    var result = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed())
    return ServerResponse.ok()
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)
         .body(result, Integer.class);
  }
}
```

So while the return type is `Mono<ServerResponse>` (as there can be only 1 response/answer) but it can contain any publisher you want. This can be a `Mono` but also a `Flux`.